# How to use sed to remove 1 or 2 dots and 1 slash?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am creating one script with is going to read a TXT file (which has many directory paths inside of it) and remove the beginning of each directory path. But, each directory path can start with `./` or `../`. How can I use SED to remove the beginning?

I know I can use 2 command lines, one to remove `./` and another to remove `../`, but how can I remove both patterns in one command line?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another. Using `^` to denote the beginning of string and `\?` to make latter `.` optional:

```
$ echo file
./foo
../bar
./period_ending./baz
$ sed 's/^\.\.\?\///g' file
foo
bar
period_ending./baz
```

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting but I guess it was a demostration since the question and both answers got downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
echo '../foo' | sed -E 's|^\.{1,2}/||'
```

Output:

```
foo
```

I switched from `s///` to `s|||` to avoid escaping `/`.